# Putting an order in the way how locks are aquired in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.1

From MySQL documentation:

*A locking read, an UPDATE, or a DELETE generally set record locks on every index record that is scanned in the processing of the SQL statement. It does not matter whether there are WHERE conditions in the statement that would exclude the row. InnoDB does not remember the exact WHERE condition, but only knows which index ranges were scanned.*

When I'm performing an UPDATE (although I would be interested about the others also, now I'm concerned with UPDATE statement), is there a way to put lock in the same order, so that to avoid deadlocks as much as possible?

I would also be very much interested if that's possible when performing UPDATE with INNER JOIN (or with multiple tables).

N.B. Deadlocks occur in my table due to concurrent updates and inserts (and even deletes).

Comment: *["MySQL enables client sessions to acquire table locks explicitly for the purpose of cooperating with other sessions for access to tables, or to prevent other sessions from modifying tables during periods when a session requires exclusive access to them."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html)*  It is enough?

Comment: @danihp table locks will cause bottlenecks if I understand it correctly. I'm searching for ordered row locking.

Comment: Also, you can first *[select ... for update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)* all your needed data. Remember to enclose it in a single transaction.

Comment: @danihp Yes, but in that case, if I understand it correctly, I will lost performance because I'll make update one by one, or if perform the same update, I think the scan of indexes will be the same, no matter if those rows are locked or not. Am I right?

Comment: If Viktor Söderqvist's comment is right. You can first grouping all your data to update in a single row: `SELECT 1 FROM sometable WHERE somecondition GROUP BY 1 FOR UPDATE; ` ( repeat for other related data in the same transaction ) and then do the update. (notice, with out select for update clause )

Comment: @danihp Sorry, but I can't see Viktor's comment. :). Or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: see deadlock video ;)

Comment: Using "manual" locks leads to more problems than you can imagine. Allowing MySQL to handle its locking and leaving it to detect deadlocks is the best possible scenario for you. You simply can't make it work any faster or any more reliable than it is doing out of the box. Any attempt to do so will result in performance loss and stability issues. You should not be afraid of deadlocks. What you should be afraid of is not reacting when MySQL tells you a deadlock occurred. Usually, this is done by wrapping queries in a transaction and if it fails due to a deadlock - simply repeat it.

Comment: @Mjh, you are right, but perhaps user has some priority processes than he want to complete in a limited time.

Answer (score 1):

You can lock all rows with a select for update statement:

```
start transaction;

--lock all needed data to be sure avoid deadlocks:
select 1 from table_1 where condition_1 for update;
select 1 from table_2 where condition_2 for update;
select 1 from table_3 where condition_3 for update;

--do updates
update in any order you want

--commit
commit;
```

In [mysql deadlock video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOERC4SzGA0) you can see how in first part user raise a deadlock:

1. User open 2 session with 2 transaction
2. User updates table `t1` on first session and table `t2` in second one.
3. User try to twist updates: he updates `t2` on first session and `t1` on second one.
4. Deadlock is raised.

On second part, user do a select for update before updates and ... ( spoiled removed ;)